# JQuery Autocomplete not working for catcomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, categories

I am trying to use the catcomplete part of the JQuery Autocomplete but it is not working.

I get this error **Jquery Object # has no method 'catcomplete'**
Here is my code

```
$('#searchForDelegate').catcomplete({
   delay: 0,
   source: data
  });
```

I have checked the Jquery and there is no function for catcomplete.

Any ideas ? Just so you know, when I use autocomplete it works fine.

Dave

Answer (score 6):

This might be stating the obvious, but `catcomplete` isn't part of jQuery UI Autocomplete.

The [Categories demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories) for Autocomplete happens to create its own [UI widget class](http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide#The_widget_factory) called `catcomplete` but that's only an example, not part of the jQuery libraries themselves.

If you need the same functionality as the `catcomplete` widget, you will need to duplicate it within your own code.

Comment: Oh yes so it does! Google's my friend so that I don't have to pay attention; but I somehow wish I did on that!